# in sqlite database or sqlitebrowser, in linux, how make a column write protected?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, case, sqlite-browser

in sqlite database or sqlitebrowser, in linux, how make a column write protected?

I am opening sqlite browser.
I create a table.
then, some columns.
eg. the column A must be write protected. But not such "option" exists as "unique key" options exists or as "not null" option.

So, i can add a bit of code to make it no other entries inserted as well no modification to this column.

How i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as defining a column as *write-protected* in SQLite.

After you inserted all the rows that you want in the table, you can create a trigger that will not allow any more insertions and another trigger that will not allow any updates of the specific column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_more_rows BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
BEGIN
   SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'No more rows allowed');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER no_updates BEFORE UPDATE ON tablename
BEGIN
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN NEW.col IS NOT old.col THEN RAISE(ABORT, 'Update of col is not allowed')
    END;
END;
```

Change `tablename` and `col` to the names of you table and the column.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2488bfd6db8ca3d92ef8404490dc11cc).

Comment: I use sqlite browser. Trigger(0). I click on this, but i cannot do a thing. Where and How you place that piece of code on the sqlbrowser?  Thank u for your help! :)

Comment: @Estatistics This is code that you can paste in any query window and execute it.